# GenericTypeHandler in mybatis does not fetch correct type object

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I would like to handle multiple "Value Objects" to wrap String object, and I would like to setup Type Handlers, but something is wrong with my configurations.

I'm using mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.1.1, and MySQL ver 8.0.16.

Here is my value objects.

```java
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class UserId extends StringValueObject {
  @JsonValue private final String value;
  public UserId(String userId) {
    super(userId);
  }

  // ...
}

@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class UserName extends StringValueObject {
  @JsonValue private String value;

  public UserName(String userName) {
    super(userName);
  }
```

I have setup my GenericTypeHandler.java as explained in [reference of mybatis 3](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers).

```java
@MappedJdbcTypes(value = JdbcType.VARCHAR)
@MappedTypes(value = {UserId.class, UserName.class})
public class GenericStringValueHandler<E extends StringValueObject> extends BaseTypeHandler<E> {
  private Class<E> type;

  public GenericStringValueHandler(Class<E> type) {
    if (type == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Type argument cannot be null");
    this.type = type;
  }

 @Override
  public E getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
    try {
      Constructor<E> constructor = type.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class);
      return constructor.newInstance(rs.getString(columnName));
    } catch (InvocationTargetException
        | IllegalAccessException
        | InstantiationException
        | NoSuchMethodException e) {
      throw new SQLException(e);
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```

```java
@Component
public class MyBatisConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public GenericStringValueHandler<UserId> userIdHandler() {
    return new GenericStringValueHandler<>(UserId.class);
  }

  @Bean
  public GenericStringValueHandler<UserName> userNameHandler() {
    return new GenericStringValueHandler<>(UserName.class);
  }
}

// Without these configurations, I got "Type Handler was null ..." error .
```

And this is my Mapper.

```java
@Mapper
public interface UserRepository {
  @Results(
      id = "user",
      value = {
        @Result(
            javaType = UserId.class,
            column = "USER_ID",
            property = "userId",
            jdbcType = JdbcType.VARCHAR,
            id = true,
            typeHandler = GenericStringValueHandler.class),
        @Result(
            javaType = UserName.class,
            column = "USER_NAME",
            property = "userName",
            jdbcType = JdbcType.VARCHAR,
            id = false,
            typeHandler = GenericStringValueHandler.class)
      })
  @Select(
      "SELECT USER_ID, USER_NAME FROM USERS WHERE USER_NAME LIKE CONCAT('%', #{userName.value}, '%')")
  public List<Users> findByUserNameLike(UserName userName);
  // ...
}
```

And I have got this.

```
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Could not set property 'userId' of 'class io.xxxxxxxxx.Users' with value 'io.xxxxxxxx.UserName@35e9d7' Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

It seems that mybatis fetched userId for type UserName.class. Please tell me what is wrong with my configuration.

Comment: Try removing `typeHandler` from the `@Result`s.

Comment: I removed `typeHandler` from the `@Result`s, but nothing has changed.

Comment: Okay. Here is one way: In addition to my previous suggestion, 1) remove `@Bean` methods that return type handlers and 2) specify `mybatis.type-handlers-package` in the application.properties.

Comment: This worked for me, and solved a problem! Thank you so much for your comment!